# Recursive function halt while there are still functions in call stack

Tags: python, recursion

I have the following recursive function that checks if two binary trees are similar.

When comparing two trees (x,y) and traversing through both trees to the left as follows:

1st call: (x = 4, y = 4)
return (sameTree(s.left,t.left) and sameTree(s.right, t.right))

2nd call: (x = 1, y = 1)
return (sameTree(s.left,t.left) and sameTree(s.right, t.right))

3rd call: (x = 1, y = None)
return (sameTree(s.left,t.left) and sameTree(s.right, t.right))

Why at the third call when the last line of sameTree (return False) is executed is the entire call stack is unwound?
Leaving the second part of the **AND** statement never reached?

[image: Tree X] [image: Tree Y]

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right


x = TreeNode(4,TreeNode(1,TreeNode(1)),TreeNode(2))
y = TreeNode(4,TreeNode(1),TreeNode(2))

def sameTree(s,t):

    if not s and not t:
        return True

    if s and t and s.val == t.val:
        return (sameTree(s.left,t.left) and sameTree(s.right, t.right))

    return False

sameTree(x,y)
```

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: `False AND anything` always gives `False` so there is no need to check `anything` - and Python knows this (and it skips part after `AND`). Similar `True OR anything` always gives `True` so there is no need to check `anything`. If you want to execute second part then you have to first run both and assign to variables and later use `AND` - `result1 = ...` `result2 = ...` `return result1 and results2`. See also wikipedia [Boolean Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)